# "This base cannot be created with PLA." PHPLDAPadmin error on login (initial entries?)

Tags: openldap, phpldapadmin

I've ended up being in charge of installing OpenLDAP with a MySQL back-end, and I'm having an issue with PHPLDAPAdmin that, while I believe I may know the problem, I have been unable to find a solution for.

I'm working on Ubuntu 14.04.1 with OpenLDAP 2.4.39, MySQL 5.5 and PHPLDAPAdmin 1.2.2.

I followed the instructions on [this site](http://www.wingfoss.com/content/how-to-install-openldap-with-mysql-on-debian6) up through the point where the writer suggested I create the test data (I had done it earlier and started fresh). So, after installing LDAP, I ran it, and it ran without problems. Then I opened PHPLDAPAdmin (which I configured to match the DN's and dc's and cn's of our OpenLDAP install), logged in with the root account, and was greeted with the error "This base cannot be created with PLA."

I searched everywhere for information relating to this, and found two helpful sources. One, here on Stack Overflow, indicated that perhaps PHPLDAPAdmin was misconfigured. I've double and triple-checked, it is not. The other, [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/problem-with-phpldapadmin-504734/#post2529987), suggested that it was due to not having set up the base RDN.

Since I have not done that, I figure that is the source of my problem. So, I've attempted to create an .ldif file per those instructions and those on the ldap quickstart guide, and came up with something like this (not sso.example.com, but with the same format).

```
dn: dc=sso,dc=example,dc=com
objectclass: dcObject
objectclass: organization
o: SBCA
dc: example

dn: cn=root,dc=sso,dc=example,dc=com
objectclass: organizationalRole
cn: root
```

However, LDAP has refused to add this. I *believe* it might have something to do with the multiple dcs, but I have been unable to find the proper syntax for adding more where it's listed on the fifth line. (Another dc entry? Comma delimiter?)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to your problem?

Answer (score 1):

For me, Error "This base cannot be created with PLA." was due to a typo in my LDAP client configuration. My client had a tree suffix ending in dc=org when it should have been cd=com. Fixing the client configuration to use cd=com fixed the problem and displayed the data tree I was expecting.

My client (management tool) is http://www.ldap-account-manager.org/

Comment: Yes as you suggested `/etc/phpldapadmin/config.php` done modification in this file and it worked ( nee to logout and login again.

Answer (score 0):

For me, it was the "$servers->setValue('server','base',array('dc=foo,dc=example,dc=com'));" line in the config.php,
I configured my slapd to use foo.example.com instead of just example.com and forgot to add the "dc=foo" part.